# Engine stall won't restart until after sitting all night

Tags: engine, ford, stall, taurus

My wife drives a 95 Ford Taurus. It stalled while sitting at a red light and wouldn't restart. We pushed it down a side street and went back the next morning. The car started right up. I called my mechanic to check it out and found nothing wrong with the car other than it is a Ford. Now my wife is afraid to drive the car. Does anyone have any ideas? There is no check engine light on either, so I cannot check for codes. So as of right now I do not have a starting point!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I suggest checking crankshaft/camshaft sensors.

Comment: Location?  I’m curious to know the outside temperature when this is occurring. I’m wondering about low fuel pressure and fuel vapor lock.

Comment: Even if the light is not on there may still be pending codes. For a car to run you need fuel, air, and spark. If one goes missing, you're walking. To even begin to guess at what is wrong we need to know which one went missing. It is common to attach gauges/scantool to a car where the driver can see them and go for a drive.

Comment: I've had this happen to my car with an overheating fuel pump/sending unit. The pump overheats and quits, then the car will start running again once it cools down. The sending pump is often inside the fuel tank its self and uses the liquid fuel to keep it cool. Do you drive the car with low levels of fuel often?

Comment: "...it is a Ford." lol there's your problem. If you can, hook up your diag equipment and try to recreate the conditions when it stalled.

Answer (score 1):

Although it was a Dodge, not a Ford, my electric in-tank fuel pump failed in a similar fashion. The car would occasionally stall at red lights or on very smooth highways (causing me to have to pull to the shoulder). The car would not restart at the time, but it would restart 30 minutes later. I realized that the car never stalled while driving in the city. An internet search suggested it might be the fuel pump binding-up when fully warm. Bumpy city roads shook the pump loose and kept it functioning, but highway driving caused a stall. Waiting 30 minutes after stalling allowed the pump to cool, and the car started. So, the next time it stalled on the highway, I crawled under the car and whacked the fuel tank near the pump to shake it loose. The car started immediately. I replaced the fuel pump and I never had a problem again. NOTE: Along the way, I spoke to dealership service writers. They suggested expensive repairs that would not have solved the problem. They never suggested the fuel pump might be the problem.